# Cpanel deploy yml file project to multiple paths/domains

Tags: deployment, cpanel

I am using Cpanel to host my website and I have two domains. I am trying to get the yml file to deploy to two directories. I would like it so that when I go to the git version control option in Cpanel and update 
 and deploy all files and folders are deployed in both locations for each website.

```
deployment:
    tasks:
      - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/userName/public_html
      - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/userName/website.pizza
      - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
      - /bin/cp -R assets $DEPLOYPATH
      - /bin/cp -R images $DEPLOYPATH
```

Putting two export Deployment Paths does not seem to work and will not deploy to both locations. If anyone knows how to do this please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official CPanel documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git+-+Deployment#GuidetoGit-Deployment-Requirements) does not mention that scenario.

But [this thread](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-customize-cpanel-yml-in-this-scenario.661865/post-2707217) shows a more elaborate set of tasks, so check if this sequence would work:

```
deployment:
    tasks:
      - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/userName/public_html
      - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
      - /bin/cp -R assets $DEPLOYPATH
      - /bin/cp -R images $DEPLOYPATH
      - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/userName/website.pizza
      - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
      - /bin/cp -R assets $DEPLOYPATH
      - /bin/cp -R images $DEPLOYPATH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked great! I was looking on the documentation and it did not explain this. I really appreciate it!